# Specify Azure key in Spark 2.x version

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to access a wasb(Azure blob storage) file in Spark and need to specify the account key.

How do I specify the account in the `spark-env.sh` file?

```
fs.azure.account.key.test.blob.core.windows.net 
   EC5sNg3qGN20qqyyr2W1xUo5qApbi/zxkmHMo5JjoMBmuNTxGNz+/sF9zPOuYA==
```

WHen I try this it throws the following error

```
fs.azure.account.key.test.blob.core.windows.net: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it is not clear that the Spark you used is either on Azure or on local.

For Spark running on local, refer this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2013/04/25/access-azure-blob-stores-from-hdinsight/) which introduces how to access Azure Blob Storage from Spark. The key is that you need to configure Azure Storage account as HDFS-compatible storage in core-site.xml file and add two jars hadoop-azure & azure-storage to your classpath for accessing HDFS via the protocol wasb[s].

For Spark running on Azure, the difference is just only access HDFS with wasb, all configurations have been done by Azure when creating HDInsight cluster with Spark.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using spark local and I added a core site xml in my spark/conf directory and added the key for my blob storage as given here- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/07/13/accessing-azure-storage-blobs-from-spark-1-6-that-is-running-locally/